# ¿Cómo mostrar el progreso de una función PHP a través de AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy haciendo una función en mi controlador que está llena de iteraciones y combinaciones. El proceso de ejecución de la función es largo, y busco una forma de mostrar en la vista el porcentaje de progreso de ejecución de esta función.

Ahora mismo, desde la vista, hago una petición AJAX que ejecuta la función en cuestión en mi controlador y cuando termina (como a los 2 minutos) me devuelve una respuesta JSON con el "Todo OK".

Para intentar a esto añadirle el estado de progreso,he probado a actualizar una variable de sesion por cada iteración de la función de mi controlador, que contiene el porcentaje del proceso y he creado una petición AJAX en la vista que cada 2 segundos pida el valor de esta variable de sesión para así mostrarlo en la vista.

Pero el resultado de esto último es que hasta que no se termina de ejecutar en el server la función principal principal, no se ejecuta la petición que solicita el porcentaje de progreso.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto? Como una sola petición AJAX que vaya recibiendo respuestas cada X tiempo o algo así? 
He visto que casi todo lo que hay por aquí tiene mas que ver con la subida de archivos, pero esto creo que para mi caso no sirve...

Un saludo

Comment: te explico con ajax se realiza una llamada la cual se cierra solo una ves, para ver el proceso mas que ajax ***yo utilizaria observables*** una libreri para hacer eso es Rxjs, ahora si quieres forzar tu solucion con ajax, te aviso que es el costo de escalar va hacer mayor. te dejo un video [enlace]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERK6S3CfFcU&list=PLSUqL2t8VZCqkBd5slTd7xll8YQIjf9wS

Answer (score 0):

Hice una funcion para enviar los datos de vuelta desde la funcion que tiene un tiempo de ejecución extenso. Espero que te sirva y te sea útil.

```
//Esta es la funcionalidad activada por tu botón
$('.tuBoton').click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
            url : {tuURL},
            type : {tuTipo},
            data : {tusParametros}, 
            dataType : 'json',
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 

            xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                var new_response = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.responseText.lastIndexOf("{"));
                var result;
                try 
                {
                     result = JSON.parse(new_response);                         
                     if(result.message != "progress")
                     {

                        if(result.message == "Success")
                        {
                            //Funcionalidad en este caso
                        }
                        else if(result.message == "Fail")
                        {
                            //Funcionalidad en este caso                                
                        }
                        else if(result.message == "Warning")
                        {
                             //Funcionalidad en este caso
                        }
                        else if(result.message == "Error")
                        {
                             //Funcionalidad en este caso
                        }
                        else if(result.message == "tuMensajePersonalizado")
                        {
                             //Funcionalidad en este caso
                        }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        //Funcionalidas en este caso    
                     }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        console.log(Exception);
                        //Funcionalidad en este caso
                    };
            }, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
                 //Funcionalidad en este caso, aca ya termino de hacerlo todo

            }, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) {
                    console.log(evt); 
            }, false);

            return xhr;
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                //Funcionalidad en este caso, antes de empezar con la peticion ajax
            },
        }); 
        }
```

});

```
    //funcion en php que envia los mensajes
    //puedes poner tantos elementos como desees en el array
    //revisa que esten puestos de forma correcta para que no te de una exepcion en el JSON.parse() del Ajax
    public static function  send_message($id ,$message, $progress, $status, $time = "-") {
    $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress, 'status'=>$status); 
    echo json_encode($d);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

 public static function  funcionExtensa(){
        $params = $_POST['tuParametro']; //si lo usas
        dondeSeaQueMetisteLaFuncionDeArriba::send_message(0,'progress',              0,"Iniciando...");
           $i = 0;
           while($i < 100)
           {
             sleep(1);
             ondeSeaQueMetisteLaFuncionDeArriba::send_message($i,'progress',           $i,"Procesando...");
           }
           dondeSeaQueMetisteLaFuncionDeArriba::send_message(100,'progress', 100,"Terminado...");
    }
```